# I need help determining if this kind of data is nominal or ordinal

Tags: mathematical-statistics

I'm driving myself crazy anyways, I'm leaning towards ordinal as the question is in regards to someone's socioeconomic status. I would think it would be ordinal, but I am unsure. The wording is something like: "Describe your socioeconomic class. "I didn't have enough, I had enough, I had more than enough". If it is ordinal, then what differentiates this from asking someone what their single favorite season is of the four?

Comment: Please rewrite this putting the assignment first, your answer second, and then your question to the forum.

Answer (score 2):

The example you give is clearly ordinal as there is an implied order to the answers you have listed for your given question (even if that assessment is subjective). In particular, there is a minimum and a maximum bound to the possible answers which makes the ordered sequence ordinal.

The issue of which is someone's favorite season is nominal. While there is a cyclic order, there is no starting and end point as to which season comes first or last. Hence there is no minimum or maximum bound to the ordered sequence of seasons so it is nominal.

Comment: On seasons, my take is different. The conclusion to draw is that the nominal-ordinal-interval-ratio classification is incomplete and doesn't match the rich variety of data out there. Sure, seasons have cyclic order, but regarding season as nominal implies that Autumn (Fall), Spring, Summer, Winter is as good an order as any other, but I would be surprised at any one who used that order in graphs or tables or any other kind of analysis.  Cyclic order is a twist on ordinal as customarily presented, but it is richer than just nominal.

Comment: @NickCox. The important point in my answer is the existence of the minimum and maximum bound for it to be ordinal. As for seasons, this is still nominal (same as days of the week). Sure, they may have pseudo-ordinal attributes but they are still nominal, even if a special (richer) type of nominal

Comment: I don’t feel obliged to take any distinction between nominal and ordinal seriously when it does not match vital distinctions about data.

Comment: Season *could* be reasonably be treated as an ordinal variable, for example if we ranked them according to average temperature.  Perhaps, in terms of coldness :  *Winter  >  Spring = Fall >  Summer* .  I could imagine where this kind of classification would make sense.

Comment: @NickCox, if you have a conviction with you view you can be constructive and propose an answer...but don't feel obliged...

Comment: I’ve made a constructive comment on your view on seasons. It isn’t a conviction; it is argued.  I disagree and I have proposed another view. As for the question on class or status, no dissent: the categories are ordered or ordinal.

Answer (score 0):

I did not understand the last part of the question, What season are you referring to,
according to your example, socio-economic class is an ordinal variable,
because it has inherent ordering in variable levels.

Ordinals variable makes sense when there are more than two levels in a variable,
for example, status of work, I will order the variable as
status of work : (Not done, in progress, done)  or (done, in progress, Not done).

If it had categorised into two level, Done and Not done, then I can treat it as Nominal variable or as ordinal variable it doesn't matter

Comment: I found this hard to follow. Can you get a colleague to help with your English?